# Codeception test returning [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException] InternalError: too much recursion

Tags: codeception

Test fails with `[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException] InternalError: too much recursion` when trying to execute $I->see() on a specific piece of text.

When analyzing the source code I see there's 250k lines of HTML code, so it's causing some sort of a bottle neck. I was wondering if there's a way to identify this issue without having the whole test fail?

I tried wrapping it in try/catch, but it didn't help.

[image]

### UPDATE

```
Browser: Geckodriver
Version: Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.5.6
```

Code

```
        try {
            $this->see($text);
            $isFound = true;
        } catch (\PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException $e) {
            $isFound = false;
        }
```

Comment: Do you use Selenium, ChromeDriver or GeckoDriver?
Show the code that you used for catching exception.

Comment: @Naktibalda hi, sorry forgot to add. Just updated the question.

Comment: Catch that UnknownErrorException. Upgrade to newer version of Codeception, 2.5.6 is 3 years old.

Comment: @Naktibalda yep that fixed it. Plus the markup itself was about 10mb per page which is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

updated codeception 2.5.6 which is 3 yrs old and it fixed the issue. markup was over 10mb per page which is abnormally high.